# R (Shiny) grid.circle and viewport output text only

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to draw a circle on a `viewport` but the only output I get is text. My ultimate aim would be to draw a circle on top of a plot. This is my code:

```
library(reshape)
library(grid)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("The Bomb Problem"),
  fluidRow(
   column(2, numericInput("numberOfPoints", "Number Of Points:", 0)),
   column(2, numericInput("radius", "Radius:", 0.5, min = 0, max = 1)),
   column(2, actionButton("btnRun", "Run"))

  ),
  mainPanel(
    vp <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0.5,width=0.9, height=0.9),
    pushViewport(vp),
    plotOutput(outputId = "points", width = "100%"),
    grid.circle(x=0.6, y=0.4, r=0.3, draw = TRUE)
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$btnRun, {
    x<-sample(0:input$numberOfPoints, input$numberOfPoints, rep=TRUE)
    y<-sample(0:input$numberOfPoints, input$numberOfPoints, rep=TRUE)
    output$points <- renderPlot(plot(x, y), height = 800, width = 800)
    df <- melt(data.frame(x,y))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the only output I get is :

```
 0.5npc 0.5npc 0.9npc 0.9npc centre FALSE 0 0 0 0.5 GRID.VP.13

 0.6npc 0.4npc 0.3npc GRID.circle.10
```

In other words, the `grid.circle` and `viewport` are not drawing any objects, they just output their properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out; by plotting both the circle and plot in the renderPlot method within observerEvent:

```
require(plotrix)
require(grid)
require(reshape)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("The Bomb Problem"),
  fluidRow(
   column(2, numericInput("numberOfPoints", "Number Of Points:", 0)),
   column(2, numericInput("radius", "Radius:", 0.5, min = 0, max = 1)),
   column(2, actionButton("btnRun", "Run"))

  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "points", width = "100%")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$btnRun, {
    x<-sample(0:input$numberOfPoints, input$numberOfPoints, rep=TRUE)
    y<-sample(0:input$numberOfPoints, input$numberOfPoints, rep=TRUE)
    output$points <- renderPlot({
      plot(x, y)
      draw.circle(0.5, 0.5, (input$numberOfPoints / 2) * input$radius, nv = 1000, border = NULL, col = NA, lty = 1, lwd = 0.5)
    }, height = 800, width = 800)
    df <- melt(data.frame(x,y))

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```